# UIMenuController Reappears after selecting a menu item

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, webview, uimenucontroller

I have a `UIMenucontroller`, where I have added a menu item named "highlight" which I am using for adding highlight to selected text in `UIwebview` using the following JavaScript :

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function load(){window.document.designMode = 'On';window.document.execCommand('backColor', false, 'Yellow');window.document.designMode = 'Off';} load();"];
```

But when I click on highlight button in `UIMenuController`, it highlights the selected text but `menuController` doesn't dismiss (or actually dismisses for a microsecond and then reappears).

What have I done wrong here?

```
BOOL isYellow = [currentColor isEqualToString:@"rgb(255, 255, 0)"]; 

UIMenuItem *notesMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:(isYellow) ? @"Delete Note" : @"Add Note" action:@selector(addNote)]; 
if (!isYellow) { 
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:notesMenuItem,nil]]; } 
else { 
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]]; 
}
```

Comment: I bet the issue is not in that javascript but in the way you instantiate the `UIMenuController`. Could you please post that code?

Comment: @Vineet Kundu: edit your answer and add the code there, rather than posting as a big unreadable blob as a comment. :)